# Convert Excel 2010 formulae to Arrays using VBA

Tags: arrays, excel

Good day,

I have been looking for this all day long, but could only find manual workarounds.

When I refresh my table data in Excel 2010, it causes a #N/A in my formulae, ranking some data. I have now created a text copy of the formulae, which I can copy back, BUT the Array formula would require me to press F2 and CSE for EVERY line.

How can I get VBA to use the current formula in the cell, and just add the {} to ensure it is an array formula again?

The typical formula would look like this

```
    =sum(1*($G36<$G$2:$G$43))+1+IF(ROW($G36)-ROW($G$2)=0,0, SUM(1*        
    ($G36=OFFSET($G$2,0,0,INDEX(ROW($G36)-ROW($G$2)+1,1)-1,1))))
```

This means that every formula in every row would be unique.

So I'm basically looking for a VBA script that can change all highlighted cell in the column of my choosing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the cells you wish to change and run:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        r.FormulaArray = r.Formula
    Next r
End Sub
```